# How to duplicate an openldap DB with different user credential? (SLADP-LDAP)

Tags: openldap

The remote LDAP server accepts only anonymous login.
I setup a windows proxy openldap using LDAP backend.

What I would like to do is to authenticate the user requesting the proxy openldap.
May I know if anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question that you want to authenticate and authorize LDAP clients using the LDAP proxy. Furthermore I assume that the remote LDAP server does not contain accounts with password.

The LDAP proxy configuration is just a database and you can define ACLs for granting access to this proxy DB. Furthermore OpenLDAP supports defining several databases. So you can have a local database for the client accounts with password which you can then reference in the ACLs for the proxy database.

If you have to use a single database you can augment the LDAP proxy DB with the [slapo-translucent](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-translucent) overlay which allows to locally store additional attributes along remote entry.